# Find all the links in the database that do not have a trailing slash

Tags: mysql, regex

There are some links in my database that do not have a trailing slash, and for consistency sake, I want all links to have one.

All the links are in this form `href="http://mysite.com/page/item/"`

Now there are some links that look like this `href="http://mysite.com/page/item"` and `href="http://mysite.com/page/item"`.

Now I can not find out on what page they are, but they are somewhere in the db, can I use phpmyadmin and regex to find them?

If so, can anyone help me with setting up the regex code, I still can not wrap my head around regex.

Comment: It is mysql, phpmyadmin has a feature to use a regex string to search with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find all entries with the [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) operation, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE href REGEXP '[^/]$'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE href NOT REGEXP '/$'
```

`[^/]`: Match any character which is not a slash; `$`: Match end of string.